# how do I transform JSON from one format to another?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am building a simple web **scraper** on Node.js. I am using Express.js, Request and Cheerio as well. I am trying to scrape the following url : http://www.houzz.com/professionals/c/Nashville,-TN

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

    url = 'http://www.houzz.com/professionals/c/Nashville,-TN';
    
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        //console.log(html)
        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var title = [], contact = [], review = [], description = [];
            var json = { title : "", contact : "", review: "", description: ""};

            $('.pro-title').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                title.push(data.text());
                console.log(title);
                json.title = title;
            });
            
            $('.pro-phone').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                contact.push(data.text());
                console.log(contact);
                json.contact = contact;
            });
            
            $('.pro-review-string').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                review.push(data.children().first().text());
                json.review = review;
            });
            
            $('.pro-description').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                description.push(data.text());
                json.description = description;
            });
        }
        
        fs.writeFile('houzz.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){
            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the houzz.json file');
        });
        
        res.send('Check your console!');
    }) ;
});

app.listen('8081');
console.log('Port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

A sample of the outputted `houzz.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "title": [
        "Marcelle Guilbeau, Interior Designer",
        "Country Flooring DIrect",
        "Eric Ross Interiors, LLC",
        "Hermitage Kitchen Design Gallery",
        "William Johnson Architect",
],
    "contact": [
        "(615) 815-9309",
        "(615) 646-0366",
        "(615) 472-8236",
        "(615) 843-3310",
        "(615) 292-4017",

    ],
    "review": [
        "77",
        "1",
        "14",
        "14",
        "15",
],
    "description": [
        "Marcelle takes her clients on a journey, drawing out their needs to create an oasis that reflects their personal sense of style and renews their connection to those things about...\t\t\tRead More\n\t\t\t",
        "Country Flooring Direct is the local flooring option that will handle your flooring needs. Give Country Flooring Direct a call and find out why lower overhead means lower prices.\t\t\tSee my projects\n\t\t",
        "Eric Ross Interiors exists to create beautiful interiors and a luxury design experience for its clients.  We are committed to creating whole room environments for our clients in...\t\t\tRead More\n\t\t\t",
        "We are a total design center that offers the finest in custom cabinetry, with the best possible level of creativity, design and service. We are located within Hermitage Lighting Gallery.\t\t\tSee my projects\n\t\t",
        "William C. Johnson Architect, LLC is a small, full service architectural design firm. Since 1985, WCJA has helped clients achieve their design goals, from small residential...\t\t\tRead More\n\t\t\t",
]
}
```

How do restructure the `houzz.json` file and make it look like this:

```
{
0:
  [
    title:
    contact:
    review:
    description:
1:
  [
    title:
    contact:
    review:
    description:
   ]
```

Comment: Your desired output is poorly formatted JSON. You shouldn't use numbers as property names, and you can't have an array of properties.

Comment: Do you know how to fix that? I probably need to query the DOM elements in a loop.

Comment: It should be noted that the terms for that site include: "You expressly are prohibited from any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools in your use of the Site."

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are grabbing the content in a disordered way.

You should be getting each "vcard" class and then iterating through the elements you want inside of that. (pro-title, pro-phone, etc)

The structure of the DOM elements already helps you keep it organized.

```
vcard
    pro-title
    pro-phone
    pro-review-string
    pro-description

vcard
    pro-title
    pro-phone
    pro-review-string
    pro-description
```

So the code looks something like this.  You might need to play with the $(this).find()

```
  var allmycards=[];
 $('.vcard').each(function (i, elem) {
     var title = [], contact = [], review = [], description = [];
     var json = { title : "", contact : "", review: "", description: ""};
    $(this).find('.pro-title').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            title.push(data.text());
            console.log(title);
            json.title = title;
        });

        $(this).find('.pro-phone').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            contact.push(data.text());
            console.log(contact);
            json.contact = contact;
        });

         $(this).find('.pro-review-string').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            review.push(data.children().first().text());
            json.review = review;
        });

         $(this).find('.pro-description').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            description.push(data.text());
            json.description = description;
        });
        allmycards.push(json);
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. This was exactly what I was looking for. However, when I try to write the array `allmycards` to the file `houzz.json` it does not get written. This is how I am writing the file - `fs.writeFile('houzz.json', JSON.stringify(allmycards, null, 4), function(err){ console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the houzz.json file'); });`